# GWT and Gradle build - the war file doesn't contain html page and WEB-INF dir also empty

Tags: gwt, gradle, build

I am working on a GWT application and want to use Gradle as a build tool.
Went thorough with various post on internet but none of them is really complete.

I followed couple of blogs as given below:
https://blog.eveoh.nl/2012/01/using-google-web-toolkit-with-gradle/
and
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/gradle/gradle-gwt-integration-example/

I downloaded the example from these blogs but still not working.

War file doesn't contain html host page and also WEB-INF folder comes empty in war. 
When I try to hit the URL generated by gradle build, I am not able to see any html page there hence getting not found message.

I was trying to run sample given in second link.

Could anyone please help me to give complete example of GWT with Gradle?
Example which create proper war file.

That will be great help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [GWT Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin) which have a lot of [examples](https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/tree/master/examples) and [documentation](http://steffenschaefer.github.io/gwt-gradle-plugin/doc/latest/eclipse).

By the way, this is the first result in Google for "gradle gwt"...